# Problem with the bib file (total bold style in references)

Tags: bibliographies

[image: Hi! I have a problem with my references. The half of them is in total bold and the other half not. I use \bf command but only for the year, for example \bf{2016}. Could you please have any idea why there is this problem?]

Here is an example of my bib file:

```
@article{nikol16, 

  author = {...},

  journal = {...},

  year = {{\bf 2016}},

  volume = {...},

  pages = {1}}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  it looks like bold only takes effect with reference [66], so showing the code for references [65] and [66] would be more helpful, along with a small compilable file that uses this information.

Comment: most likely you have a `\bf` that is not scoped but you should not use `\bf` in latex anyway and the year field should just be the year without formatting. Any formatting should be applied by the bibtex style not be in the bib file,

Comment: In order to find out exactly what is going on with your document we would need to see more code, ideally an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). What we can see from the code you showed us so far is the use of `\bf` in your `.bib` file, that should be avoided as David Carlisle explains, you should not use formatting commands in the `.bib` file (there are a few exceptions, but your use case is not one of them).

Comment: Thank you so much everybody! The problem was fixed! Yes, you are right, the problem was the use of \bf in my .bib file. Now, I delete every \bf and the references are without the total bold fond. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have a `\bf` that is not scoped with `{}` in the bib file, but you should not use `\bf` in latex anyway and the year field should just be the year without formatting. Any formatting should be applied by the bibtex style not be in the bib file,